# I need to remove Java Script tags using regular expressions and JRegex

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all the Java Script tags and the content in between and style tags from the HTML code of web pages.So far I've come up with this expression :

```
"(<[ \r\n\t]*script([ \r\n\t>]|>){1,}([ \r\n\t]|.)*?</[ \r\n\t]*script[ \r\n\t]*>)|(<[ \r\n\t]*noscript([ \r\n\t>]|>){1,}([ \r\n\t]|.)*?</[ \r\n\t]*noscript[ \r\n\t]*>)|(<[ \r\n\t]*style([ \r\n\t>]|>){1,}([ \r\n\t]|.)*?</[ \r\n\t]*style[ \r\n\t]*>)"
```

I use JRegex library to work with regular expressions. When I test it in any regex tester it works just fine, but once I run my program - it all crashes down with this error report:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$LazyLoop.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$LazyLoop.match(Unknown Source)
..................................
```

And it keeps on going forever. If anyone can give me an advice on this one - I'll be very grateful.

Comment: first of all "([ \r\n\t]|.)" makes no sense at all. use DOT_ALL or something.
"([ \r\n\t>]|>)" also makes no sense. put ">" outside

Comment: You got me on the right track, thank you!

Comment: That's not JRegex you're using, it's Java's native regex package.  JRegex is one of the third-party libraries that were created before Java got its own regexes in JDK 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an HTML parser and just remove the `<script>` and `<style>` nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I can resolve this problem. I use a regular expression for remove script tags and the content in between script tags using this regular expression:

```
@"<(script|SCRIPT)[^+]*?>[^>]*?<(/\script|SCRIPT)>"
```

Comment: If you type 4 spaces at the start of a line (or select it and type CTRL+K), then it formats it as code.